# How do you know a solution space contains the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra

In a linear system

$$x - 2y + 3z = 0 \\
-3x + 7y -8z = 0 \\
-2x + 4y -6z = 0 $$

The solution space is $\{(2s -3t,s,t) \mid s,t \in \mathbb{R}\} = \operatorname{span}\{(2,1,0),(-3,0,1)\}$

How do we know that the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ contains the origin?

Comment: Is (0,0,0) a solution to the system? It's easy to check. Plug in 0 for x, y and z and see if it makes all three equations true.

Comment: This is what's called a "homogeneous system of equations"  The origin *always* satisifes the system, just plug in zeros for all the variables and you'll see all equations hold true.

Comment: Are you asking how to know that the solution space that you give is correct, or how to know that the solution space that you give contains the origin?

Comment: You might want to check that solution space. [The intersection of two non-parallel planes (1st and 3rd equations are the same) is going to be a line.]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution set contains the origin because if you plug $x=y=z=0$ into your equations, each of them becomes $0=0$ which is true.

If you have *nonzero constant terms* in one or more of your equations, this will not be the case, and you need to offset the span by a known particular solution, if there are any solutions at all.

Answer (score 9):

This is what's called a "homogeneous system of equations"  The origin *always* satisifes the system, just plug in zeros for all the variables and you'll see all equations hold true.

If you don't have zeros on the right hand side then it's harder, you have to row-reduce the augmented matrix of coefficients in that case.